# ListFragment can't scroll

Tags: android, listview

I'm a beginner of android programming as well as a beginner of English, so first of all I want to say sorry for my English may be difficult to understand

I try to add a listview in a fragment that extends listfragment. What I believe is that I can scroll the listview without extra settings, But somehow the listview is seem to be fixed and cannot be scrolled

Here is the fragmentpage_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#949497">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:divider="#949497"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my PageFragment that extends ListFragment

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.*;

public class PageFragment extends ListFragment{
    public static  final String ARGS_PAGE="args_page";
    public int mPage;

    private ArrayList<String> aString=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> urlString=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> images=new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayList<MyNews> myNewses=new ArrayList<>();
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;



    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page,ArrayList<MyNews> myNewses){
        PageFragment fragment=new PageFragment();

        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARGS_PAGE, page);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.myNewses=myNewses;

        return fragment;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage=getArguments().getInt(ARGS_PAGE);

        for(int i=0;i<=myNewses.size()-1;i++){
            aString.add(myNewses.get(i).getNewsTitle());
            urlString.add(myNewses.get(i).getSource_url());
            images.add(myNewses.get(i).getImages());
        }

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page,container,false);


        myAdapter= new MyAdapter(inflater,aString,images);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), aString.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),WebActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        intent.putExtra("source_url",myNewses.get(position).getSource_url().toString());
        intent.putExtra("image",myNewses.get(position).getImages().toString());
        intent.putExtra("title",myNewses.get(position).getNewsTitle().toString());
        intent.putExtra("origin",myNewses.get(position).getOrigin().toString());
        intent.putExtra("news_id",myNewses.get(position).getNews_id().toString());
        intent.putExtra("category",myNewses.get(position).getCategory().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and finally is my Adapter for the listview

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import java.util.*;


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> images_url=new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, ArrayList<String> list,ArrayList<String> images){
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.list = list;
        this.images_url=images;
    }

    public DisplayImageOptions getDisplayOption() {
        DisplayImageOptions options;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)              
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                .build();
        return options;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(null == convertView){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            viewHolder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.textView.setText(list.get(position).toString());
        if(images_url.get(position)=="NoImage"){
            viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.me);
        }
        if(MainActivity.canConn) {
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(images_url.get(position), viewHolder.imageView);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.me);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return null;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

for can't scroll I mean I can scroll the listview on the android simulator on my PC, but can't scroll it with dragging the mouse as well as drag it with my finger on the phone

Comment: Replace  this android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" with  android:layout_height="match_parent"